# How to decorate a consumer functional interface with retry in resilience4j

Tags: resilience4j

Currently DecorateConsumer.java in resilience4j-all library is not providing a method to decorate for Retry(only supports Circuit Breaker, RateLimiter and BulkHead).

Retry.java class also does not provide this option

I have a consumer function public void call(String key) which internally performs a rest Call with the value of key.

But the resilience4j docs mention "You can decorate any Callable, Supplier, Runnable, Consumer, CheckedRunnable, CheckedSupplier, CheckedConsumer or CompletionStage with a Retry."

How can we decorate a Consumer Functional Interface with Retry in resilience4j

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
String key = "key";
Runnable runnable = () -> helloWorldService.sayHelloWorldWithName(key);
Decorators
    .ofRunnable(runnable)
    .withRetry(Retry.ofDefaults("id"))
    .run();
```

or just

```
Runnable runnable = () -> helloWorldService.sayHelloWorldWithName(key);
retry.executeRunnable(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no **decorateConsumer**, but you can write it yourself:

```
public static <T> Consumer<T> decorateConsumer(Retry retry, Consumer<T> originalConsumer) {
  return (T input) -> retry.executeRunnable(() -> originalConsumer.accept(input));
}
```